# Scalar differential operator

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

How do I prove that the scalar differential operator , ($ u.\nabla$), is a unit operator, i.e., ($u.\nabla)u = u$ ?
My attempt included writing $u$ in its component form but I cannot reach the final result.

Comment: What is $u$? A function?

Comment: Yes, a scalar field function.

Comment: How does your "scalar differential operator" $(u.\nabla)$ operate on a general scalar field $f$? Given that we can check whether in the special case $f:=u$ it does what you claim.